# how to trigger particular app in android by default

Tags: android, email, android-intent, vcf-vcard, android-implicit-intent

Say if, I want to restore an `.vcf` file / send an email from my app and i use `Implicit Intents` to achieve it.

But, it pops up some options like (for `vcf files:` **Editor**, **people**. for `email: gmail`, **mail**).

I want only one application to be opened by **default** (Without prompting the user).

How can i do that?

Comment: You can't, for very good reasons.  It would be a security hole if you could.  Android ensures that I am in control of what apps open for what actions, not you!

Comment: Why would the user want this? Were you planning on just randomly choosing some app to open?

Comment: I felt that for sending a mail, it showed options and i was irritated and felt that my users no need to be prompted. That's why